# php callback function in class not being called

Tags: php, class, function, callback, gearman

Given this line of code to callback a function and the callback function itself:

```
Class MyClass {
    public function doThings() {
        $this->gearman->client->setCompleteCallback("workerCompleted");
    }

    public function workerCompleted() {
        echo "worker is completed!";
    }
}
```

I get `Message: GearmanClient::setCompleteCallback(): function workerCompleted is not callable`

The `setCompleteCallback` method expects a function name in quotations, but how do I call a class method? `$this->"workerCompleted"` obviously is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->gearman->client->setCompleteCallback("workerCompleted");
```

should be

```
$this->gearman->client->setCompleteCallback( array( $this, "workerCompleted"));
```

Because you're specifying a callback to a member function, which requires an array of the object (or classname) that needs to be called, along with the name of the function. More info at [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: This method gets rid of the errors but does nothing. My function just has a simple echo and it isn't being performed. Why could that be? Does it have to be returned as @Dasun mentions in his answer?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be returned. The problem now lies with gearman, as it is not invoking your callback. This is the proper way to specify your callback, now you need to figure out why gearman isn't calling it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used the `doBackground` function to send the code the gearman server? That indeed doesn't use the Callback, since you by definition don't care about the job status and results in your application code.